# Dresser conversion to media stand - hinge help required

Tags: hinges

[image: Dresser conversion to media stand]

Hi, I need some help please. I am upcycling an old dresser into a media stand. I want to put hinges on the top left and right drawer so they fold open to 90 degree. 
The issue I have is the drawers are curved therefore I will need a hinge that opens and pushes out. My only requirement is the front face when closed is flush, I don't mind a gap when the drawer front is open so that PS4, Direct TV, DVD player can be used.

Can anyone tell me the name of the hinges I would need to use?

Thank you
Chella

Comment: Are you planning for these to be hinged vertically like a typical door, or for the fronts to open up or down? Hinging vertically is fairly simple, but if the hinges need to be on the top or bottom, you will be hard pressed to make it work without some very large reveals and heavy modification on the back side.

Comment: Hi, I am planning on the fronts opening down to 90 degrees, not vertically

Answer (score 2):

A few suggestions:

[blum-170-degree-face-frame-hinge](http://www.rockler.com/blum-170-degree-face-frame-hinge?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_term=&utm_content=pla&utm_campaign=PL&sid=V9146&gclid=Cj0KEQjw-73GBRCC7KODl9zToJMBEiQAj1Jgfzp88Va8ehLpd_9HiT_cLMwbSUEnAmzar17cdEMjlqoaAvo98P8HAQ)

[soss-door-hardware-208-invisible-door-hinge](https://www.atgstores.com/door-hinges/soss-door-hardware-208-invisible-door-hinge_5866959.html?ppc=2615&af=2615&cm_mmc=sce_google&s_kwcid=AL!4500!3!186135949198!!!g!292994803897!&gclid=Cj0KEQjw-73GBRCC7KODl9zToJMBEiQAj1Jgf9OUYOo94JTt_sdlvbWdqGyFytKd6Ph5u6C2YPOiR-IaAoF28P8HAQ&ef_id=VvsIQQAABPCdLV8U:20170320185346:s)

[soss-door-hardware-218-invisible-door-hinge](https://www.atgstores.com/door-hinges/soss-door-hardware-218-invisible-door-hinge_5866995.html?ppc=2615&af=2615&cm_mmc=sce_google&s_kwcid=AL!4500!3!186135949198!!!g!292994803897!&gclid=Cj0KEQjw-73GBRCC7KODl9zToJMBEiQAj1Jgf_KePwKx6PENZuseJiX8VewvswBNg0jdVIwQlMDKjr4aAk378P8HAQ&ef_id=VvsIQQAABPCdLV8U:20170320185255:s)

Comment: @Chellaza Soss hinges are one of the better options for this type of thing but be aware they are unforgiving in terms of alignment so you must be very careful when marking out to drill your holes.

Comment: Thanks, it certainly sounds like it. I had my suspicions well I was googling how to do this and not much came up at all.

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to get Soss hinges to work, but they are danged finicky, and require someone with more than average skill to install them.  You might be able to finagle a 35mm cup hinge of some kind ("Blum" is one company that makes them) but if its curved where the cup hole is bored that will increase the amount of expertise required, if its even possible.

The fact that the "door" will be 2.5x wider than it is tall will mean you will be fiddling them forever, because no matter how perfectly you align them, they will always sag.  You have very little tolerance in those openings.

Unless you use a piano hinge, but those will eventually sag, too, and you cannot hide them. There is a way to sort of hide a piano hinge in an overlay scenario, but not in this inset one.

Good luck!

"Upcycle".  Thats funny.

Comment: haha well upcycling is taking a sadly damaged but nice piece of furniture and giving it some love :-)

Comment: This sounds like a job for an expert, or to perhaps remove the top drawers completely and make them open "slots" to hold all the equipment. Thank you for your advice, much appreciated.

Comment: I hate to tell anyone not to do something, but you do have odds against you on this one.  Truth be told, its probably careful experts like me who stifle the opportunity for discovery :) - it isn't impossible, just danged tricky. BTW, you don't need a hinge that opens and pushes out if you bevel that leading edge.

Comment: I would rather someone be honest! Thanks for the tip on beveling the leading edge

Answer (score 0):

Maybe to late.. but try these hinges.. POJJO Home Depot $
24.50 a pair 1.25 x 3.75 90 Degree Extend Tip Out Hidden Hinge in Chrome (1 Pair)[image]